# The use of return; For a beginner, from a different perspective c++

Tags: c++, return

I've just started programming and I've come to hear the standard beginner's definition of "the use of the return value in main" a lot, but it does not get to the point I am trying to understand. So, yes a return value 0 for 'int main' for example signifies that the programme running was successful and since main is of int datatype, 0 reflects this.

BUT what is the point of this? Won't the computer already know that the code was successful or not? Surely, we could write a flawed code and then return 0, and by that logic, we (the programmers) are saying this code is correct but the compiler actually executes the programme and if it's wrong/flawed it simply cannot operate on it.

Please use explanations that a beginner could understand.

Comment: this is a broad question, maybe not for SO, but a good one from beginner's standpoint. When a program is run in separation, sure, you don't care *that* much about its return value. Perhaps its side-effects are enough (i.e. a file has been saved). This changes dramatically, when you invoke programs in sequences or chains - when one execution should depend on outcome of another. Then, different exit codes can mean different things, and maybe execution shouldd be halted.

Comment: Compiler compiles, it does not execute the code

Comment: @hauron Is this really too broad? We don't have to explain all the nuances of exit codes etc., just explain what `main`'s return value actually means in the context of the OS. Wouldn't take a book or even a chapter, I think.

Comment: @Angew I think the answers here are fine, to a question that is in my opinion too broad for SO. This is a thing that should be simply read, explained in at least a chapter. But really, this boils down to "what is SO"? Is it for professionals seeking answers to challenges, or should it educate the newbies as well? Imo it should rather point to resources for the latter group.

Comment: Just in passing, note that there are three portable return values for `main`: 0, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. 0 indicates success. The other two are defined in `<stdlib.h>` and `<cstdlib>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return code of your program ain't about crashing, its about a functional kind of failure.

For example, the program [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) defines exit/failure code 0 as successfully found and 1 as not found. While value 2 gets used for invalid input.

Within scripting, this can be used for some automated logic without the user needing a user to interpret the results.

As you are a beginner, I would recommend to always return zero as you are focusing on how to learn the language. Looking into how applications can connect to each other via exit codes is adding unneeded distraction/complexity.

Answer (score 5):

A program can fail, because some expectations are not met.

For example, a program which count the number of lines in files passed as arguments to `main`  would fail when one of the arguments is not a valid file name, or if, for some reasons, that file could not be opened. And if you code such a program, you'll need to explicitly add some program logic (that is, several or many source code lines) for that. A good programmer don't allow his program to [crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_(computing)) (even with wrong or missing input or arguments).

A simple program which copies a source file into a destination requires two arguments. If `main` is not given two arguments, it should fail. If the first argument does not name a valid and accessible file, the program should also fail. If the copy could not be achieved because some disk is full, that program should also fail.

The return from `main` is, in practice, not some *arbitrary* integer. On Linux and many POSIX systems, it should be some integer between 0 and 255 (with 0 meaning "successful execution", and other exit values are for failures). See [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) & [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for more.

By some *convention* (which you need to document) the failure codes (in practice there are few of them, usually less than a dozen and quite often 0 -named `EXIT_SUCCESS`- on success and 1 -named `EXIT_FAILURE`- on failure) could tell about the failure reason. See for examples the documentation of [tar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html), [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html) programs, [grep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), etc.

BSD unixes define some conventions in [sysexits](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%204.3-RELEASE&format=html) (but Linux programs generally don't use that).

[Shell scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) can  easily test and handle the exit code.

Read also about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). Successful command-line programs (e.g. [cp(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)) could often be silent. Error messages would go (by convention) to [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)).

As you would learn more about C programming, you'll understand that **conventions matter a** big **lot** (and it is important to document them). Study also the source code of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) programs, e.g. on [github](http://github.com/).

Remember that you don't write code mostly for the computer, but also -and mostly- for the person (perhaps you in a few months, perhaps some future developer working at your company, when you'll be a professional developer) which would have to improve your code....

Answer (score 3):

The return value from main indicates if something worked in a "business" sense, not in a "technical" sense. If the program has a technical flaw, main probably won't return at all, as the program will probably have crashed, or the return value will be meaningless, due to undefined behaviour.

The return value is used in things like search programs to indicate if something the program was interested in was found or not. The computer can't know what to return in these sorts of cases, as it has no understanding of the semantics of the program.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `main`, which becomes the exit code of the process once it's done running, is not related to whether the code is correct C++, but whether it has executed correctly from the point of view of its semantics (its business logic, let's say).

While the program exists as C++ source code, returning from `main` is an instruction like any other. Having `return 0;` in `main` will not affect whether your program is a valid C++ program, and will not fix e.g. syntax errors. While being compiled, it's totally irrelevant w.r.t. correctness.

The return value of `main` comes into play *when the compiled program actually runs (already in binary form).*

That is, when you're executing e.g. `gcc ... -o myapp`, the return value of `main` does not come into play (indeed, it doesn't even exist). But when you're then executing `./myapp`, its *process exit code* (which is used by e.g. shell) is what gets set by the return value of `main`.

For example, the unix `if` command tests whether its argument returned `0` or non-`0`:

```
if ./myapp; then
  echo "Success"
fi
```

Whether the above shell script echoes `Success` or not depends on whether the process exit code of `myapp` was `0` or not, in other words, whether its `main` function returned `0` or not.

The Windows-world equivalent of such a check would be:

```
myapp.exe
if errorlevel 1 goto bad
echo "Success"
bad:
```

One common convention is to have a process exit code of 0 on success, 1 when the program couldn't complete its task (e.g. it was asked to remove a file which doesn't exist), and 2 when it was invoked incorrectly (e.g. it was given a command-line option it doesn't understand). *These* are the values `main` returns.